# show all comments to and from, in activity?

Tags: discussion, comments, recent-activity

is it possible to see all comments i've made, to and from?

preferably in activity.

Answer (score 2):

Your activity shows recent comments. Although as of now it's not possible to list only comments.

Comment: What do you mean.. Do you mean it only shows recent comments i've written? Or recent comments written to me? or recent comments from or to me? And not All comments from me or all comments to me. And how recent?

Comment: Shows recent comments by you. Recent enough to fill the screen. http://meta.superuser.com/users/42672?tab=activity http://superuser.com/users/42672?tab=activity

Answer (score 1):

**Incoming messages**

Click the **envelope** at the top of the page, it's next to your user name. Click on the **responses** tab.

**Outgoing messages**

Click on **your user name** at the top of the page, click on **activity** and cilck on **comments**.